# Cannot read property 'getFixedT' at React-Storybook

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have an error message:

```
Cannot read property 'getFixedT' of undefined. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFixedT' of undefined
at Translate.componentWillMount (webpack:///./~/react-i18next/dist/commonjs/translate.js?:78:46)
at eval (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:348:23)
at measureLifeCyclePerf (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:75:12)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:347:9)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:258:21)
at Object.mountComponent (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js?:46:35)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:371:34)
```

My example register namespace in component:

```
export default translate('example namespace', { wait: true })(MyComponent)
```

And my configure i18n.js looks like:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

export default i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    ns: [
      'example namespace',
    ],
    defaultNS: 'example namespace',
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
});
```

I haven't any idea how to solve this problem because all components work with language assets while running server in the browser. I use kadira/storybook: "^2.35.3", Maybe you have some experience how to setting storybook to load all namespace of my assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I need to add addDecorator in storybook and surrounded my story with i18 provider.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: [You can find an example from the official react-i18next docs for this exact use case here](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/storybook/stories/index.js)